# How do you get the length of a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-length

How do you get the length of a string in jQuery?

Comment: Excellent just use normal JS.

Answer (score 499, accepted):

You don't need jquery, just use `yourstring.length`. See reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp) and also [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html).

**Update**:

To support unicode strings, length need to be computed as following:

```
[...""].length
```

or create an auxiliary function

```
function uniLen(s) {
    return [...s].length
}
```

Comment: I was too, oh the joys of SO.

Comment: I bet that's just competition. :D

Comment: Artem Barger -- probably because he asked about using Jquery.

Comment: Artem Barger - probably because he was looking for the same thing as I was: a way to get the length of text contained in an HTML tag. I'm a beginner so I knew how to get the content but not its length. In that sense, genesis' answer below is better.

Comment: `"".length == 2`. How can we get the actual number of characters?

Comment: to make unicode aware lenght you need to run it following way: [...""].length

Comment: "You don't need jquery..." - that's not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 213):

The easiest way:

```
$('#selector').val().length
```

Comment: the only answer that answers the question as asked.

Comment: how is that? no where in the question does he say anything about the string coming from an `:input` value

Comment: so does this one: `len = $('#selector').is('div') ?  "someString".length : 0` and makes just as much sense...

Comment: but this still just uses javascript doesn't it? same as @Artem Barger's answer

Answer (score 44):

jQuery is a JavaScript library.

You don't need to use jQuery to get the length of a string because it is a basic JavaScript string object property.

```
somestring.length;
```

Comment: +1 for including the line 'jQuery is a JavaScript library.' Lots of answers are saying you don't need jQuery, but this may be confusing to a person who thinks that 'jQuery' and 'JavaScript' are two different things.

Answer (score 22):

**HTML**

```
<div class="selector">Text mates</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
alert(jQuery('.selector').text().length);
```

**RESULT**

10

Answer (score 22):

A somewhat important distinction is if the element is an input or not. If an input you can use:

```
$('#selector').val().length;
```

otherwise if the element is a different html element like a paragraph or list item div etc, you must use

```
$('#selector').text().length;
```

Comment: It's right Answer for this Question! Here is really defined, how gets a length of "input field" or "text" value. Additional it's possible to get html length, like `$('#selector').html().length`.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need to use jquery.

```
var myString = 'abc';
var n = myString.length;
```

n will be 3.

Answer (score 14):

It's not jquery you need, it's JS:

```
alert(str.length);
```

Answer (score 13):

same way you do it in javascript:

`"something".length`

Answer (score 4):

In some cases **String.length** might return a value which is different from the actual number of characters visible on the screen (e.g. some emojis are encoded by 2 UTF-16 units):

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length):
This property **returns the number of code units** in the string. UTF-16, the string format used by JavaScript, uses a single 16-bit code unit to represent the most common characters, but needs to use two code units for less commonly-used characters, so **it's possible for the value returned by length to not match the actual number of characters in the string**.

In Unicode separate visible characters are called graphemes. In case you need to account for this case, you'll need some lib that can split the string into graphemes, such as this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grapheme-splitter

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery :

```
var len = jQuery('.selector').val().length; //or 
( var len = $('.selector').val().length;) //- If Element is Text Box
```

OR

```
var len = jQuery('.selector').html().length; //or
( var len = $('.selector').html().length; ) //- If Element is not Input Text Box
```

In JS :

```
var len = str.length;
```