# Check if user input text less than 50 characters

Tags: javascript

I want to check the input length in JavaScript. I have the function to check whether the user input is empty or space only:

```
if(!this.content || this.content.trim() === ''){
    return
}
```

Now I want to check the user input length. If less than 50 characters system will showing an alert.

Comment: `if(this.content.length < 50) { alert }`

Comment: Just check this [tutorial](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKRyxQ?editors=1011) may this will help you.

Comment: Ya `if(this.content.length < 50) { alert }` is working, thanks for reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the length of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044105/how-do-you-get-the-length-of-a-string)

Comment: Should that be `if(this.content.trim().length < 50)`?